# Can you create a disk and an instance in with one command in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

Currently, I'm creating a disk from a snapshot. Then I wait for 60 seconds and create an instance which will use that disk as its system disk. I'm using the `gcloud` utility for this.

**Is there any way I can create the disk and the instance in one command?**

Mix of copy-pasted Python code and pseudocode below:

```
cmd_create_disk = [GCLOUD, 'compute', 'disks', 'create', new_instance,
                   '--source-snapshot', GCE_RENDER_SNAPSHOT_VERSION,
                   '--zone', GCE_REGION, '--project', GCE_PROJECT]

# wait for 60 seconds

cmd_make_instance = [GCLOUD, 'compute', 'instances', 'create', new_instance,
                     '--disk', 'name='+new_instance+',boot=yes,auto-delete=yes',
                     '--machine-type', instance_type, '--network', GCE_NETWORK,
                     '--no-address', '--tags', 'render', '--tags', 'vpn',
                     '--tags', proj_tag, '--zone', GCE_REGION,
                     '--project', GCE_PROJECT]
```

The instance uses the disk as its system disk. Waiting for 60 seconds is quite arbitrary and I'd rather leave this up to GCE, making sure the instance is indeed started with the system disk.

When you delete an instance you can specify that the disk should also get deleted. In the same manner, I'd like to create an instance and specify the disk to be created from image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boot disk can be created automatically.  You can specify the image to use for that using `--image` and `--image-project` flags in `gcloud compute instances create` command line.  You'll need to make sure to create the image first though - your current command to create the disk seems to use a snapshot rather than an image.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm not using an image. I'm using a snapshot.

Comment: You can turn your snapshot into an image by creating a disk from the snapshot (like you do in your first command) and then creating an image from that disk using "gcloud compute images create --source-disk ...".  This only needs to be done once, and after that you should be able to create VMs using that disk image for the boot disk, in one command.